# Print values from the same key in dict

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to work on my small project and I encounter the following problem that I'd like some assistance which I can't seem to figure out how would be the best way to do.

I have the following dict that contains the values as follow:

```
issue_analysis = {'Issue_Analysis': [(5, 'hyperlink_1'), (6, 'hyperlink_2'), (4, 'hyperlink_3'), (2, 'hyperlink_4'), (0, 'hyperlink_1')]}
```

I'm able to print the values individually if I do this:

```
for i, j in issue_analysis.items():
     for values in range(len(j)):
          print(j[values][0], j[values][1])

Print Result:
5 hyperlink_1
6 hyperlink_2
4 hyperlink_3
2 hyperlink_4
0 hyperlink_5
```

Now I want to add another value under the same key where the new value is actually the result that I subtract from value 1 and value 2. Here is what I do and the dict will look like this:

```
for key, values in result_all.items():
     result_difference = str((values[1][0]-values[2][0]))
     result_all[key].append(result_difference)
```

```
{'Issue_Analysis': [(5, 'hyperlink_1'), (6, 'hyperlink_2'), (4, 'hyperlink_3'), (2, 'hyperlink_4'), (0, 'hyperlink_1'), 2]}
```

If I try to print all the values:

```
for i, j in issue_analysis.items():
     for values in range(len(j)):
          print(j[values])

Print Result:
(5, hyperlink_1)
(6, hyperlink_2)
(4, hyperlink_3)
(2, hyperlink_4)
(0, hyperlink_5)
2
```

If I try to print the values like below, I'm getting an error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
for i, j in issue_analysis.items():
     for values in range(len(j)):
          print(j[values][0], j[values][1])
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to get the output as follow

```
Desire Result:
5 hyperlink_1
6 hyperlink_2
4 hyperlink_3
2 hyperlink_4
0 hyperlink_5
2
```

Would like to ask some guidance here how I can solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if statement to handle the different cases of tuples and ints.

```
for i, j in issue_analysis.items():
    for values in range(len(j)):
        if type(j[values]) == tuple:
            print(j[values][0], j[values][1])
        else:
            print(j[values])
```